# I have tried to run an existing laravel project. But during composer update I got this error:

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model, relationship

**Problem 1**

```
- Root composer.json requires gabrielbull/ups-api ^0.8.0 -> satisfiable by gabrielbull/ups-api[0.8.0].
- gabrielbull/ups-api 0.8.0 requires php ^5.5 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

**Problem 2**

```
- Root composer.json requires mehedi-iitdu/laravel-paystack dev-master -> satisfiable by mehedi-iitdu/laravel-paystack[dev-master].
    - mehedi-iitdu/laravel-paystack dev-master requires php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

**Problem 3**

```
- laravel/framework[v5.8.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev] require php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
- Root composer.json requires laravel/framework 5.8.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev].
```

Comment: PHP 8 will not work with these packages, consider updating these packages or downgrading your PHP version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error messages are quite clear. The packages you want to install require PHP 7, but you have PHP 8 installed.

Your options are:

- Downgrade your PHP version
- Upgrade the package versions you depend on, if there are newer PHP 8 compatible versions

Comment: I think it is the other way round.. Laravel 5.8 seems to be too old for PHP 8. Maybe you should upgrade/shift Larave 5.8l to Laravel 6 or require an older version of whatever you required in the first place.

Comment: Sorry, you're right! I read the number back to front.